Error when creating a PR using GitHub Actions
I keep getting this error:
pull request create failed: GraphQL: Resource not accessible by integration (createPullRequest)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Here is my workflow:
name: Update from upstream

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *' # Runs every midnight
  push:
    branches:
      - master # Change to your default branch if different

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Git
      run: |
        git config --global user.name 'github-actions'
        git config --global user.email 'github-actions@github.com'

    - name: Add upstream remote
      run: git remote add upstream https://github.com/skypilot-org/skypilot.git

    - name: Fetch upstream
      run: git fetch upstream

    - name: Checkout new empty branch
      id: date
      run: |
        BRANCH_NAME=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S)
        git switch --orphan $BRANCH_NAME
        echo "::set-output name=date::$BRANCH_NAME"

    - name: Merge upstream changes
      run: git merge upstream/master

    - name: Push to remote branch
      run: git push -u origin `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`

    - name: Create pull request
      run: gh pr create -B master -H `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S` --title 'Merge master into `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`' --body 'Created by Github action'
      env: 
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Workflow Permission granted
I did not expect this error to happen since I have included the GITHUB_TOKEN in the environment when I'm using the GitHub CLI and I also made sure to check the box for Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests in my repo's Workflow Permission Settings.

I had the same issue today.  This is mostly likely due to your workflow's permissions.
Because you are creating a PR and pushing to the repository in some of your steps, you need to add these permissions to your workflow file above:
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pull-requests: write

Hope that helps.

Firstly, I reckon "Resource not accessible by integration" could mean that you should not do that with a robot?!?
Secondly. I think the authentication information is incomplete.
I would add some statements 'echo $YOURVAR' to show that the required env variable is actually correctly set.
This should be the general way of using the action black box in github!
Always verify that the data is where you think it is, you can remove the extra code later.
Since github is not a product with a manual this could be a more effective approach to verify first, instead of wondering after why.
